# Is there a way to add a prototype to variables (numbers), and the prototype can change the variable itself?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know its a bad idea to add prototypes to native javascript objects, but I'd like to add a prototype to a variable such as `Number.limit(min, max);` where the variable can be changed by the prototype.

```
Number.prototype.limit = function(min, max) {
    if (this < min) {
        this =  min;
    } else if (this > max) {
        this = max;
    }
};
```

it appears that using `this` gives a Invalid left-hand side in assignment error

I have searched through google and stack overflow and nothing has answered my question

so is it even possible? and how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (for the most part) - the best you'll be able to do is to *return* the new value, which the caller reassigns:

```js
Number.prototype.limit = function(min, max) {
  if (this < min) {
    return min;
  } else if (this > max) {
    return max;
  }
  return this;
};
let num = 5;
let newNum = num.limit(10, 15);

console.log(newNum);
```

If you're familiar with Javascript, to understand *why* it's not possible, it might help to look at the invocation of a method *without* the implementation:

```
let someVar = <something>;
someMethod(someVar);
```

No matter what `someMethod` does, the object or primitive that the `someVar` variable name is bound to in the scope above is not changeable by `someMethod` (unless `someMethod` is also defined in that scope, which is a *bit* weird and is often not the case). Unless `someMethod` also has lexical scope of `someVar` and does `someVar = <somethingElse>`, the `someVar` will remain referencing `<something>`. Although `someMethod` may *mutate* the `<something>`, if it's an object, it cannot *reassign* the `someVar` variable name in the other scope.